# Search Field On Linking DataObject

Tags: silverstripe

I'm pretty much setting up the [tutorial 5 Mentor](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/5-dataobject-relationship-management) section as I site I'm building has teachers, so exact same concept.

When I go to link a mentor from a page, when I search the the text field, the results I get don't show the first name field, [they show the dataobject id #.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wsvl84i7iy87uu/Screenshot%202014-04-04%2013.09.26.png)

My fields are FistName and LastName on the dataobject and on the dataobject I've setup $searchable_fields & $summary_fields to match these columns, yet I still get the results above.

Also, my search field to [start shows this.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/by4fd7evrbbqi8n/Screenshot%202014-04-04%2013.22.02.png) Notice the 'partial match' in the placeholder text. Shouldn't it just show the field name?

Using 3.1 and basically just copied and pasted tutorial 5 for the mentors part. The tutorial seems to work right out of the box, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title is the default display value for pretty much any basic presentation of a `DataObject` in the CMS.
But not all `DataObject`s have a Title, so the class `DataObject` has a method `getTitle()` which returns `"#{$this->ID}`.

there are 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. overwrite `getTitle()` in your DataObject (the Mentor)

   ```
   public function getTitle() {
       return "{$this->Firstname} {$this->Lastname}";
   }
   ```
2. tell the search field thingy on the GridField to use something else than title (example code according to the tutorial)

   ```
   class Project extends Page {
       public function getCMSFields() {
           $config = new GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor();
           $autoCompleteComponent = $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter');
           $autoCompleteComponent->setResultsFormat('$FirstName $LastName');
           $mentorsField = new GridField(
               'Mentors',
               'Mentors',
               $this->Mentors(),
               $config
           );           
           $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Mentors', $mentorsField);
           return $fields;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll give this a try on Monday but sounds like it has everything covered.

Comment: Just to follow up, your 1st option to overwrite the getTitle() function doesn't work. The result returns an empty list with a small height. Your 2nd option works though.

Comment: not sure, but perhaps the first example fails because in `{$this->Firstname} {$this->Lastname}` the N are lowercase, try it with `{$this->FirstName} {$this->LastName}`

Comment: Oh right. Thanks that did it. I had just copy and pasted quickly and missed that part with the capital letter. Thanks for the solution!